# Better way for resampling data in order to keep the authenticity of the data in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, time-series

I want to resample my data, in order to have 512 seconds each interval between date time each index.
I found the `resample` method from `pandas`, but it does not work properly as the original data will be too modified in the end (the original data's authenticity would not be the same). However, I thought about a possibility if within the date time, the intervals are only 2 numbers, and they can also divided to one another (512: 4 = 128). The issue is that their occurrences could count any number.

Calculated the index's intervals by using the following code:

```
intervals = np.array(round(df.index.to_series().diff().dt.total_seconds().fillna(0)))
```

my index's intervals are like this: (as my data is recorded every 4 or 512 seconds)

`{4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 512,512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 512, 512, 512, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 512, 4, 4, 4, 4, 512, 512, 521, 512, ...}`

The issue is that sometimes the data is recorded each 4 seconds for 5 minutes (so not enough time to achieve the 512) then it could appear 512 and so on as in the example above. It is an issue because I first thought that maybe I should loop on every 512 seconds and then delete all the rows that are not within that interval. (I delete them because I need to have only the data recorded at each 512 seconds, it is not really necessary to know what it was within the interval. It would possibly make an addition, but it would change so much.)
I need to make it to be every 512, but without using the resample method as it would destroy the data's authenticity, if I observed well.

To conclude with, the two main conditions are: first respect and keep the authenticity of the data and second the data should be recorded each 512 seconds in the end.
So, I am asking you, the experts in this field, what do you think it would be the most appropriate method or algorithm for my case?

P.S.: I have been searching for other methods, like resample but better, but I did not find an appropriate one. However, I open to new ideas! Let me know if I should add other details regarding the problem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no loss of authenticity of data through `resample()`

1. have recreated a sample data set where I have I have simulated source data at *128s* intervals with gaps
2. then `resample()` to *512s* buckets
3. this can mean that there are **empty** buckets where *last* will be *NaN* and the *list* of underlying values is *empty*
4. you need to decide what you want to do in these cases.  For a case where I up-sample temperature data I `dropna()` other options would clearly be `fillna()`
5. due to presence of *NaN* you should consider `dfr = df.resample("512s")["val"].agg(last="last", vals=lambda s: list(s)).astype({"last":"Int64"})` to maintain datatype of columns (i.e. changed from *int64* to *float64*)

In conclusion there is no loss of integrity of the source data.  You need to decide how you deal with cases where there is no underlying data that fits into a *bin*

```
d = [d for d in pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2019,5,1,2), 
                          dt.datetime(2019,5,1,4), freq="128s") 
     if random.randint(0,3) < 2 ] # miss some sample times... so resampling will give NaNs

df = pd.DataFrame({"ts":d, "val":[random.randint(0,50) for x in d]}).set_index("ts")
dfr = df.resample("512s")["val"].agg(last="last", vals=lambda s: list(s))
dfr
```

**output**

```
                     last          vals
ts                                     
2019-05-01 01:59:28  27.0   [1, 41, 27]
2019-05-01 02:08:00  48.0  [14, 14, 48]
2019-05-01 02:16:32  43.0   [2, 49, 43]
2019-05-01 02:25:04  43.0          [43]
2019-05-01 02:33:36  44.0          [44]
2019-05-01 02:42:08  38.0      [39, 38]
2019-05-01 02:50:40  37.0          [37]
2019-05-01 02:59:12  25.0      [39, 25]
2019-05-01 03:07:44   1.0    [29, 8, 1]
2019-05-01 03:16:16  35.0  [12, 20, 35]
2019-05-01 03:24:48  33.0      [20, 33]
2019-05-01 03:33:20   5.0       [11, 5]
2019-05-01 03:41:52   NaN            []
2019-05-01 03:50:24   9.0           [9]
```